# Connect CLaaS container to CosmosDB

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks

I have a application running on a AKS Container and would like to use the Azure Cosmos DB for storage.  How can i set this up?

I think i just need to specify the ip address from which the requests are originating on the k8s cluster so that the cosmosdb will allow access.

Should this traffic go over the internet or is it possible to set up a connection between the vnets?

Comment: Not sure what specific issue you’re having. There is no difference in running your code in a container or elsewhere - access is the same. You can certainly choose to use a vnet - plenty of docs describing how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to CosmosDB easiest way is to just use [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-python-samples) provided by Microsoft in your app. You just provide your app a connection string to your database, here is a simple [quickstart example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-python). You don't have to open any network traffic on CosmosDB side if you use default configuration, but of course if you wish you can lock access to only selected networks. So if your containers have internet access they can also access your database.

To address your second concern to not go over internet you can get more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-sdk-connection-modes).

To allow access from existing virtual network using portal you need to go to the cosmosdb resource into firewall tab and add existing network, you should see something like this:
[image: screenshot of firewall tab content]

Comment: - I know how to get an application to talk to cosmosdb - the issue here is that cosmosdb has a firewall with a list of allowed ip addresses - so my question is if I am to use the CLaaS service how should the network be configured to ensure secure communication to cosmosdb? should we go over the internet? and in this case what is the public ip address of the CLaaS cluster? or how can i find that? Alternatively should this network traffic go over the internal VNET/Subnets in Azure and if so how can we establish this?

Comment: how do you connect the subnet for CLaaS to the subnet running cosmosdb? if the traffic goes out on the internet then the subnet ips won't be visible and I don't know what the public ip is for the CLaaS cluster - any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is the problem but you can check my edit if it helps you.